# Set the value of a column in Table B With Max value of column in Table A

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables like this:

```
Application  
ApplicationID  ApplicationDesc  VersionNo
1              APP1             1
2              APP2             1
3              APP3             1
4              APP1             2 
5              APP2             2
6              APP1             3

Order
OrderID      ApplicationID      OrderDescription
1            1                  Belongs to APP1 version 1
2            4                  Belongs to APP1 version 2
3            6                  Belongs to APP1 version 3
```

I want to update the column ApplicationID in the table Order with the ApplicationID of latest version of the corresponding application.

I want the data to look like this:

```
Order
OrderID      ApplicationID      OrderDescription
1            6                  Belongs to APP1 version 1
2            6                  Belongs to APP1 version 2
3            6                  Belongs to APP1 version 3
```

How do I accomplish this? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a common table expression to find the newest ApplicationID, then join your update statement to the CTE:

```
;WITH cteNewest(ApplicationID, NewestApplicationID)
AS(
  SELECT
     ApplicationID
    ,MAX(ApplicationID) OVER(PARTITION BY ApplicationDesc)
  FROM Application
)

UPDATE o
SET o.ApplicationID = new.NewestApplicationID
FROM [Order] o
JOIN cteNewest new
  ON o.ApplicationID = new.ApplicationID;
```

Have a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73dc8/12)